# turing machine decidability proof

Tags: turing-machines

An exercise problem once again has me stumped on a Turing Machine decidability proof.

We are given an alphabet with the strings 0 through 9.

Along with this, we have x as the infinite string of all digits in PI. (3141592...)

With L ⊆ Σ*, the language L = {A ∈ Σ*| A is a sub-sequence of x}.
(from what I understand, the definition here of a sub-sequence is  having a $x = x_1x_2x_3... $ where each $x_i$ can be constructed from Σ, then a sub-sequence of x is a finite string of the form $x_{i1}x_{i2}x_{i3} ... x_{ik}$ where $i_1 < i_2 < i_3 < ... < i_k.$

Other than that I have no idea where to start with this...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And *what* is the question now? (Both the problem statement, and yours.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you come up with a Turing machine that writes the decimal expansion of $\pi$ to tape?
2. Can you come up with a Turing machine that, given a string,
   a separator, and the decimal expansion of $\pi$ on the tape,
   determines whether the string occurs as a subsequence of $\pi$? (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216343/does-pi-contain-all-possible-number-combinations)).
3. Given such machines, can you 'weave' them into a single machine?

Comment: What happens if the input is _not_ a subsequence of the decimal expansion of $\pi$?